# Can mysql-database save strings casesensitive, like UNIX?

Tags: mysql, unix, case-sensitive

Is it possible to store "Filename" and "filename" in a mysql-database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean, store ‘Filename’ and ‘filename’ in a column that has a UNIQUE constraint (such as a PRIMARY KEY)?

If so, then yes, but you must tell MySQL to use a case-sensitive collation when `CREATE`​ing or `ALTER`​ing the table. This can be done with `VARCHAR(...) COLLATE some_collation_cs` ([see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html)) or simply `VARCHAR(...) BINARY`.

Comment: Thank you! Setting the column to `varbinary` did it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to store "Filename" and "filename" in a mysql-database?

If the column you're inserting to is `UNIQUE`, make sure that its collation is case sensitive:

```
CREATE TABLE t_ci (test VARCHAR(50)  PRIMARY KEY COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci);

INSERT
INTO    t_ci
VALUES
('Filename'),
('filename');

-- Fails

CREATE TABLE t_cs (test VARCHAR(50)  PRIMARY KEY COLLATE utf8_bin);

INSERT
INTO    t_cs
VALUES
('Filename'),
('filename');

- Succeeds
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will always preserve the case when you store strings.

When you search for a string it normally does a case-insensitive search.  This depends on the collation, but the default is case-insensitive.

To do a case-sensitive search you can change the collation:

```
SELECT x FROM table WHERE y LIKE '%Filename%' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

See [case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to save "File" and "file"? and not get that as a duplicated entry?